# Смена эмулятора android

Tags: android, android-studio, эмулятор

Не открывал Android Studio пару дней, на машине установлен только один эмулятор Pixel 2 (Pie 9.0).
Сейчас открыл один из проектов, собрал и увидел это
[image: Мой новый эмулятор]

Вопрос: как это могло произойти? Эмулятор поменялся сам